# Does sp_updatestats cause tables to be inaccessible in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, statistics

Does updating statistics cause tables to be inaccessible?  In other words, can you run this procedure without downtime?

Specifically for SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No (it doesn't make them inaccessible), and Yes (you can run it without downtime).

sp_updatestats can be run against a live database without downtime.

Comment: What's the "Yes" part of your answer?

Comment: The question asked if it causes tables to be inaccessible, to which I said No.  The question then asked "in other words, can you run this without downtime", to which I said Yes.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2000, you can run this procedure without causing downtime. I doubt that has changed in later versions.